# VT102 serial emulator for Android phone?

Tags: android, terminal-emulator

I can't find a VT102 type serial emulator for android.

The serial output I want to monitor using a phone implements VT102 escape control sequences for formatting a live status table. This works on Putty on a Linux Mint laptop but I can't find a similar app for an android phone that recognises the VT102 control sequences.

Comment: Probably worth saying that the Putty app I found does not have this feature.